# Error: "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required" on Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have an error message on Django 1.4:

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

It happened when I tried using a template tag like: `{% for v in values %}`:

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    ...
Django Version:     1.4.5
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djorm_hstore/fields.py in __init__, line 21
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/var/www/',
 '.',
 '',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']

Server time:    sam, 13 Jul 2013 16:15:45 +0200
Error during template rendering

In template /var/www/templates/app/index.html, error at line 172
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

172     {% for product in products %}

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

                            response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view

                    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py in inner

                return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    ...
▶ Local vars
./app/views.py in index

            context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py in render_to_response

        return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py in render_to_string

            return t.render(context_instance)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                return self._render(context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in _render

            return self.nodelist.render(context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node

                return node.render(context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render

            return compiled_parent._render(context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in _render

            return self.nodelist.render(context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node

                return node.render(context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render

                result = block.nodelist.render(context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in render

                    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node

                return node.render(context)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render

            len_values = len(values)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/paginator.py in __len__

            return len(self.object_list)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __len__

                    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in iterator

                        obj = model(*row[index_start:aggregate_start])

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py in __init__

                    setattr(self, field.attname, val)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djorm_hstore/fields.py in __set__

                value = self.field._attribute_class(value, self.field, obj)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djorm_hstore/fields.py in __init__

            super(HStoreDictionary, self).__init__(value, **params)

    ...
▶ Local vars
```

It happens too when I try to access on a hstore queryset:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)

File "/home/name/workspace/project/app/data/commands/my_command.py", line 60, in handle
    item_id = tmp[0].id,

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 87, in __len__
    self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in iterator
    obj = model(*row[index_start:aggregate_start])

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 300, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.attname, val)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djorm_hstore/fields.py", line 38, in __set__
    value = self.field._attribute_class(value, self.field, obj)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djorm_hstore/fields.py", line 21, in __init__
    super(HStoreDictionary, self).__init__(value, **params)

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

The code is:

```
tmp = Item.objects.where(HE("kv").contains({'key':value}))

if tmp.count() > 0:
            
    item_id = tmp[0].id,
```

I'm just trying to access the value.  I don't understand the "update sequence" message.  When I use a cursor instead of `hstore queryset`,  the function works. The error comes on template rendering too.  I just restarted `uwsgi` and everything works well, but the error comes back later.

Comment: Please post the code that shows what's in `values` and `tmp`. While code is missing, -1 (possibly temporary) for this question.

Comment: I will add it as a comment. I got the error because I used a list instead of tuple. This raises the error: `dict(['A',"b"])` while this doesn't `dict([('A',"b")])`

Answer (score 524):

Just ran into this problem. I don't know if it's the same thing that hit your code, but for me the root cause was because I forgot to put `name=` on the last argument of the `url` (or `path` in Django 2.0+) function call.

For instance, the following functions throw the error from the question:

```
url(r'^foo/(?P<bar>[A-Za-z]+)/$', views.FooBar.as_view(), 'foo')
path('foo/{slug:bar}/', views.FooBar, 'foo')
```

But these actually work:

```
url(r'^foo/(?P<bar>[A-Za-z]+)/$', views.FooBar.as_view(), name='foo')
path('foo/{slug:bar}/', views.FooBar, name='foo')
```

The reason why the traceback is unhelpful is because internally, Django wants to parse the given *positional* argument as the *keyword* argument `kwargs`, and since a string is an iterable, an atypical code path begins to unfold. Always use `name=` on your urls!

Comment: This answer is very good because it covers an obscure error that is difficult to figure out. Even seasoned Django developers may fall in this particular trap.

Comment: Especially if you also use the `Router.register` method of Django RestFramework. It looks very similar, the difference is the `name` kwarg...

Comment: FYI I also received this error using Django 2.0 style `path` URL. Forgot to use the kwarg and had this: `path('foo/', views.foo, 'foo')`. I had to change to `path('foo/', views.foo, name='foo')`

Comment: @inostia That's a good point. I'll update the answer to let people know that the issue still persists.

Comment: I know its late, But this is brilliant insight into how django is considering the args passed. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This came up for me using python, and even though the context was different, this answer helped me because it pointed me in the direction of string iterability. In short, I'd passed a string instead of a tuple containing the string AND the argument I actually wanted to iterate. Thanks

Answer (score 106):

I got this error when I was messing around with string and dictionary.

```
dict1 = {'taras': 'vaskiv', 'iruna': 'vaskiv'}
str1 = str(dict1)
dict(str1)
*** ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

So what you actually got to do to get dict from string is:

```
dic2 = eval(str1)
dic2
{'taras': 'vaskiv', 'iruna': 'vaskiv'}
```

Or in matter of security we can use literal_eval

```
from ast import literal_eval
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Yes, use `json.loads(dict1)`. Using `eval` can pose security risks

Comment: @duhaime this solution will cause another error `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes` if `my_dict` have `keys` in `single_quotes` for **Example** 
```my_dict = {'single' : true}```

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh Did you find way to convert ' to " ?

Answer (score 33):

Error in your question is raised when you try something like following:

```
>>> a_dictionary = {}
>>> a_dictionary.update([[1]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

*It's hard to tell where is the cause in your code unless you show your code, full traceback.*

Comment: This confirms that the cause is not included in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer next time I will copy the traceback, but it's weird, when it happened with the template tag, just after uwsgi restart, the result displayed properly, so there was result

Comment: @user2575627, Why don't you post code/traceback now? Update (edit) your question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post code/traceback because it was urgent to repair/fix the service, so I didn't copy the traceback the first time

Comment: @user2575627, Could you post codes around /home/name/workspace/project/app/data/commands/my_command.py line 60?

Answer (score 19):

I faced the above mentioned problem when I forgot to pass a keyword argument **name** to url() function.

**Code with error**

```
 url(r"^testing/$", views.testing, "testing")
```

**Code without error**

```
url(r"^testing/$", views.testing, name="testing")
```

So finally I removed the above error in this way. It might be something different in your case. So check your url patterns in **urls.py**.

Comment: 2019 and the same stackoverflow answer still saves me every time

Comment: Yeah, thank you v  much. SO is really a great platform for developers, scientists and others.

Answer (score 17):

Here is how I encountered this error in Django and fixed it:

### Code with error

```
urlpatterns = [path('home/', views.home, 'home'),]
```

### Correction

```
urlpatterns = [path('home/', views.home, name='home'),]
```

Comment: This happened to me as well, thank you! Do we know what is going on here?

Comment: @ValidusOculus I am not very sure, looks like you have to use kwargs. You can read more about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/

Answer (score 10):

Here is the reproduced error.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update([(1,)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
>>> 
>>> d
{}
>>> 
>>> d.update([(1, 2)])
>>> d
{1: 2}
>>> 
>>> d.update('hello_some_string')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
>>>
```

If you give the sequence and any element length is 1 and required two then we will get this kind of error. 
See the above code. First time I gave the sequence with tuple and it's length 1, then we got the error and dictionary is not updated. second time I gave inside tuple with with two elements, dictionary got updated.

Comment: I'm getting the same error using shortucts.redirect and trying to send the response to an external page.. e.g. '
               [code] return redirect("https://msn.com")[/code]

Answer (score 10):

#### Solution»

Pass a keyword argument *name* with value as your view name e.g `home` or `home-view` etc. to `url()` function.

#### Throws Error»

`url(r'^home$', 'common.views.view1', 'home'),`

#### Correct»

`url(r'^home$', 'common.views.view1', name='home'),`

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue and found that it was due to wrong parameters.
In `views.py`, I used:

```
return render(request, 'demo.html',{'items', items})
```

But I found the issue: `{'items', items}`. Changing to `{'items': items}` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it turned out that missing 'name' in the urls.py was the cause of problem.

Answer (score 3):

Another scenario that causes this error:

```
dict('{"a":1}')  # gives the error
```

One way to achieve what you want is to use `eval`

```
eval('{"a":1}')  # gives {"a":1}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('',HomePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my `get_context_data` in one of my views was returning `return render(self.request, 'es_connection_error.html', {'error':error});` in a try/catch block instead of returning `context`

Answer (score 2):

The error should be with the params. **Please verify that the params is a dictionary object**. If it is just a list/tuple of arguments use only one * (`*params`) instead of two * (`**params`). This will explode the list/tuple into the proper amount of arguments.

Or, if the params is coming from some other part of code as a JSON file, please do `json.loads(params)`, because the JSON objects sometimes behave as string and so you need to make it as a JSON using load from string (loads).

```
super(HStoreDictionary, self).__init__(value, **params)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I hit this error calling:

```
dict(my_data)
```

I fixed this with:

```
import json

json.loads(my_data)
```

Comment: this solution will cause another error `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes` if `my_dict` have `keys` in `single_quotes` for **Example** 
```my_dict = {'single' : true}```

Answer (score 2):

check in your dictionary whether if you have single or double Quotation mark in your key or value!

```
dict1 = {'hello': 'world', 'programmer's': 'have girlfriend'}
```

to resolve it you can simply convert your dictionary in to string and then use replace method!

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem when I was trying to convert json string to dict.

Input: `'{\r\n  "resource_id": "id",\r\n  "resource_type": "resource"\r\n}'`

Using `dict()` to convert the string to `dict` gave me this error. The correct way would be to use `json` module.

Example: `json.loads(input_str)`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue when trying to invoke the update method with a parameter of a wrong type.
The expected dict was:

```
{'foo': True}
```

The one that was passed was:

```
{'foo': "True"}
```

make sure you check all the parameters you pass are of the expected type.

Answer (score 1):

I too had a similar type of problem . The solution is simple . just dont try to enter NULL or None value in values or u might have to use Something like this
`dic.update([(key,value)])`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending one parameter incorrectly; it should be a `dictionary object`:

- **Wrong:** `func(a=r)`
- **Correct:** `func(a={'x':y})`

Answer (score 0):

This behavior will also occurs when using `get_or_create` method in the following example below one will obviously get that error:

`state,_ = Status.objects.get_or_create('Pending')`

To resolve this you will add the the respective key and value.

i.e like this `state,_ = Status.objects.get_or_create(name='Pending')`

Comment: Life saver! Needed this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your URL path I fixed this issue by changing the URL.

path('reset_password_email/', requestpasswordresetemail, "request-rest-email")

Instead of use

**path('reset_password_email/', requestpasswordresetemail, name="request-rest-email")**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue so this is how I solved it ( by doing an eval and strip )

```
aggr = {}
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        for k, v in dict(eval(line.strip())).items():
            aggr.setdefault(k, 0)
            aggr[k] = aggr[k] + v
    
print(aggr)

print(aggr)
```

The data I was reading was a text file with a dictionary objects

```
{'unknown': 298, 'a4a815d631c805ccd10dd2f1548baa57': 9724, '22b5a0ff959ce0b4036716cc0c2df68b': 1341, 'd186fde596dffaab46260765c7fcba61': 2052}
{'unknown': 323, '49e5357782510659cf083356f7d2a1ab': 9826, 'a4a815d631c805ccd10dd2f1548baa57': 9812, 'b615930608b8dcd217de7904d4463efb': 2409}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from ast import literal_eval

c = "{'taras': 'vaskiv', 'iruna': 'vaskiv'}"
c= dict(literal_eval(c))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was messing around with string and dictionary.

```js
dict1 = {'taras': 'vaskiv', 'iruna': 'vaskiv'}
str1 = str(dict1)
dict(str1)
```

or to be specific

```js
query_result = req_db_session.query(app_config_model.APPCONFIG).with_entities(app_config_model.APPCONFIG.value).filter(app_config_model.APPCONFIG.name == 'test_me').first()
print(query_result, type(query_result))
print('--------------------------')
print(type(query_result))
# prints <class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>
print(dict(query_result))
# throws error
```

*** ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
So what you actually worked was:

```js
query_result = req_db_session.query(app_config_model.APPCONFIG).with_entities(app_config_model.APPCONFIG.value).filter(app_config_model.APPCONFIG.name == 'test_me').first()
print(query_result, type(query_result))
print('--------------------------')
print(type(query_result.value))
# prints <type 'unicode'>
print(json.loads(query_result.value))
# prints parsed dictionary
```