# dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required when loading page

Tags: python, django

i saw multiple same topics but non of them solved my problem .
I just created a django project , build an app called `News`. 
when i try to load page i got this error :

> dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Here is first `urls`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('News.urls'))
]
```

And Here is `News` urls :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.LoadHome.as_view(), 'home_page')
]
```

And finally my view :

```
class LoadHome(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>
> Django Version: 2.0.5 Python Version: 3.6.5 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'MyUser.apps.MyuserConfig',  'News.apps.NewsConfig'] Installed
>   Middleware: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "A:\Python\techProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     35.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "A:\Python\techProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     113.         resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
>
> File
>   "A:\Python\techProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py"
>   in resolve
>     496.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
>
> File
>   "A:\Python\techProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py"
>   in resolve
>     496.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
>
> File
>   "A:\Python\techProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py"
>   in resolve
>     345.             kwargs.update(self.default_args)
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at / Exception Value: dictionary update
>   sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Whats the problem ?

I think the reason is my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py but i cant find any problem in it .

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'MyUser.apps.MyuserConfig',
    'News.apps.NewsConfig'
]
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? Right now it is a bit guesswork.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem traceback added

Comment: @Mehdibmp Try to had something to the url, a different path than '' or use '$'!!

Comment: @Micolho i changed it to /news/... but still got the same error

Comment: @Mehdibmp did u change it like `r'^news/$'` ?

Comment: @Micolho yeah, this is a bad problem :(( my admin panel not working too , but when i remove News include it will work

Comment: @Mehdibmp what does this app `'MyUser.apps.MyuserConfig'` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171926/discussion-between-micolho-and-mehdi-bmp).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required" on Django 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610732/error-dictionary-update-sequence-element-0-has-length-1-2-is-required-on-dj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your urls.py you got and error:

**Your urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns=[
url(r'', views.LoadHome.as_view(), 'home_page')
]
```

**And the correct is:**

```
urlpatterns=[
url(r'', views.LoadHome.as_view(), name='home_page')
]
```

Comment: You shouldn't have spaces around the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.LoadHome.as_view, 'home_page')
]
```

You are supposed to call the `as_view` method:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.LoadHome.as_view(), 'home_page')
                                #  ^^
]
```

See Django's [class-based-views docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/).