# Get Object by pk in URL in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to retrieve objects from the ORM by the "pk" in URL.
Here's what I am trying

This is my Url:

```
path('api/dispatchhistoryitem/<int:pk>/', views.dispatchhistoryitemsview.as_view(), 'dispatchhistoryitem'),
```

Views.py

```
class dispatchhistoryitemsview(ListAPIView):
    queryset = ItemBatch.objects.all()
    serializer_class = holdSerializer

    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        items = get_object_or_404(ItemBatch, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        serializer = holdSerializer(items)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializer.py

```
class holdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemBatch
        fields = "__all__"
```

But when I run this it says :

> ValueError at /api/dispatchhistoryitem/43/
>
> dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

What is that I am doing wrong here ? Please Help!

Comment: Probably this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19670235/2696165

Comment: I don't understand why you are using a ListView if you want to get a single item. Use a DetailView, then you won't need to define `get` at all.

Answer (score 6):

I think essentially the problem is that you use the wrong view. A `ListAPIView` is used to retrieve, well, a list of objects.

You can here use a [**`RetrieveAPIView`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview) which already implements the boilerplate logic. If your URL contains a `pk` parameter, it can automatically filter on that `pk`, so there is no need to implement this logic yourself:

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView

class dispatchhistoryitemsview(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = ItemBatch.objects.all()
    serializer_class = holdSerializer
```

Furthermore, as [@ruddra says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534470/get-object-by-pk-in-url-in-django-rest-framework/57534969?noredirect=1#comment101534309_57534470) you should use a named parameter, since the third parameter is the kwargs:

```
path(
    'api/dispatchhistoryitem/<int:pk>/',
    views.dispatchhistoryitemsview.as_view(),
    name='dispatchhistoryitem'
),
```

Comment: This makes sense but adding "name=" in the path solved the problem as stated by ruddra in comments

Comment: @RahulSharma: ah yes, but that means you have a `{% url ... %}`, `reverse(..)`, `redirect(..)` somewhere (not in your question) to the `dispatchhistoryitem` view.