# Textarea field return a string dictionary to convert dictionary in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on textarea  which I pass a string dictionary format and get this value in views.py file it give string value like this
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHS1a.png)

but when I want to convert in into diction is cause an error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQYzX.png)

here is my views.py file
[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOfV0.png)
here is html file:
[check.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKGLt.png)

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610732/error-dictionary-update-sequence-element-0-has-length-1-2-is-required-on-dj

Comment: i saw it but in my situation its not work my input is {
"hr_remarks": "#TOKEN_HR_REMARKS",
 "status": "#TOKEN_STATUS",
 "ticket_id": #TOKEN_TICKET_ID
}
in this format when i use eval it give me syntax error