# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required, at the output of pprint in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pprint, environ

I get the error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is
> required

at the output of this line:

`pprint.pprint(dict(os.environ['MOTECOM']), width= 1)`

I'm using Python 3.6.2 on docker container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required" on Django 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610732/error-dictionary-update-sequence-element-0-has-length-1-2-is-required-on-dj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error when messing around with dict and str.
Using [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) should help:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(literal_eval(os.environ['MOTECOM']), width= 1)
'MOTECOM value'
```